# Combine quantile and continuous models in plot (cph, rms)?

Tags: r, continuous, rms

I would like to combine continuous and quantile models in the same plot to compare and contrast the two approaches (xtile is a function that returns the quantile as factor):

```
q.s <- cph(inc ~ rcs(exposure,3), data=data)

q.q <- cph(inc ~ xtile(exposure,3), data=data)

p.s <- Predict(q.s, exposure, fun=exp)

p.q <- Predict(q.q, exposure, fun=exp)
```

`ggplot.Predict` gives a nice plot of either model - but I would like to combine both. Is this possible?

I have added an example - which I hope might illustrate what I would like to generate.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ZvSq.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try this where plot1/2 are your quantile and continuous plots (can change heights, widths, number of columns, number of rows):

```
p1 <- ggplot.Predict(..plot1 options here...) 
p2 <- ggplot.Predict(..plot2 options here...) 

library(gridExtra)
grid.arrange(p1, p2, 
        ncol=2, nrow=1, widths=c(2,2), heights=c(2))
```

For more information, check out the `gridExtra` package.

Comment: Thanks - but I would like to combine them in the same plot; they have the same coordinates (x for quantiles is the median).